# What could make a service STOP on win32?

Tags: service, windows

A service (Python 2.7) on XP which is supposed to never stop, stops for an unkwown reason at midnight every day, so I have to restart it every morning.

The service worked well for a year, but something must have change on the system a few days ago (maybe the Python version or pywin32) and now it stops every night.

The service doesn't freeze, it stop nicely and the event log shows "the service has entered the stop state" (or something like that).

What could make that service stop ?

Comment: does it stops exactly at m8 (0:00) ? sometimes pywin32 stops, when there is no ram available - have you checked the health of your machine ?

Comment: Please don't cross post the identical question to more than one Stack Exchange site - http://superuser.com/questions/358441/what-could-make-a-win32-service-stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what service you are talking about, I can only suggest some answers. However, the first thing that comes to mind is that there is some file system logging operation that it cannot complete at midnight - my guess is log file rotation.

I would check the directories for this service; find out if you have reached the max size of a file, or the max numbers of files in a directory.